# Loading a JSON string for storage into pyMongo

Tags: python, json, pymongo, urllib

I am using the urllib library to open a url and read in the data. The data is then converted to a string and needs to be input to a collection in pymongo. My current code is the following:

```
import pymongo, urllib.request, json
from pymongo import MongoClient

reponse = urllib.request.urlopen('Website with JSON on it')
plstr = str(response.read())

module4 = MongoClient()

mycol= module4.payload

output = mycol.insert_one(plstr)

print(output.inserted_id)
```

I can't figure out how to have MongoDB properly read in the JSON so I have it converted to string but this is not necessary to the completion of the problem. Any way to have MongoDB store the JSON data would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted before I was done the writeup

Comment: I don't think a json file is a valid collection name. `module4[payload]` means `payload` is a collection, but `payload` is json data which is highly unlikely to be one (perhaps even impossible).

Comment: Thats the question. How can I write the JSON data to a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can simply pass your document to `insert_one()`

```
import requests
import json
import pymongo

# You need a pymongo version > 3.0
print pymongo.version

r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
your_document = json.loads(r.text) # let's suppose your_document is list of dicts 

# connection on the default host and port
client = pymongo.MongoClient()

# your db name
your_db = client.db_name

# your collection name
your_collection = your_db.collection_name

# let's suppose you want to load the first dict of the list
result = your_collection.insert_one(your_document[0]) 

# print the ObjectId of the inserted doc
print result.inserted_id
```

from the doc: `your_document` must be a mutable mapping type. Use the `dict` you have just received from the Website

Comment: That was one of the ways that I tried to do it but when I feed a string in as your_document and execute the insert_one method, i get the following error: "'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert_one' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists."

Comment: It sounds pretty odd. `insert_one()` is available form version 3.0. Which `pymongo` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.5.1

Comment: Ok, can you edit the original post with the code with `insert_one`? What `type` of `your_document` are you passing in?

Comment: Currently, your_document is a string but thats because I made it a String. It was initially a bytes object because thats what urllib returns. I also tried calling the json.dumps() method on the plstr.__dict__ object but it tells me that the object is not JSON serializable. And yeah I'll edit the original now.

Comment: @bnoos I've just written down a working example. It should work. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped : )

Comment: It appears that your_document is not being created as a dict. I get an error on the insert_one line that states "TypeError: document must be an isntance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping". Once I found out that it was a list, I changed your insert line to `result = my_collection.insert_one(your_document[0]) ` and it printed out encoded text.

Comment: Of course you have to manage properly the returned data. They can be a single doc like [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1), or a collection of docs like [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). The solution above should fix your problem. Is it ok?

Comment: Yeah you're answer helped immensely and the code is correct as long as you change `result = my_collection.insert_one(your_document)` to `result = my_collection.insert_one(your_document[0])`. Once you edit that, I can mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Edited with comments to underline that the example is for a list of dicts!